# sort 2 arrays based on other array key

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays:

```
$data[ 1234567 ] = irrelevant value;

$info[ 1234567 ] = array( price = x, category = x )
```

I need to sort, maybe I have to change $data to array( 1234567, x ),
but how can I sort $data based on price in $info?

Comment: Please add an example with real data.

Comment: What's the irrelevant value you want to sort? Is it a string?

Comment: sorry if the question was bad, I was only trying to sort based on price from $info, I solved it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

what I did was loop through $data and get the values from $info, so I ended up with:

```
$data[ x ] = array( price = x, category = x, irrelevant value );
```

and used this function I found on php.net:

```
           function multisort (&$array, $key) {
                 $valsort=array();
                 $ret=array();
                 reset($array);
                 foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
                    $valsort[$ii]=$va[$key];
                 }
                 asort($valsort);
                 foreach ($valsort as $ii => $va) {
                     $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
                 }
                 $array=$ret;
             }
```

so this way I didn't need the ID as keys since all data was in the array now